# query for model instances that are indirectly related

Tags: django

I've got 3 models. I'd like to write a query in django to find all reviews that are related to Carts that are related to jobs that are complete. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do this.

```
class Review:
   cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)   

class Job:
   cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)   
   complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Cart:
   name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   amount = models.IntegerField()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 1):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Review.objects.filter(cart__job__complete=True)
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "*through*" relations.

This will thus retrieve all `Review`s for which a related `Cart` exists for which a related `Job` exists that has `complete=True`.

Comment: Willem, you're an absolute beast. I didn't realize that this worked through relationships like this.